# ZF2 phpunit.xml <directory>

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2

I've been following the Zend Framework 2 tutorial on unit testing, but once I reached the section '[A failing test case](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#a-failing-test-case)' my test actually passed instead of failing.

I've changed the Album Controller to become a definite failing test e.g. $this->assertTrue(false) and it still passes.

However, when I edit the phpunit.xml file and change `<directory>./AlbumTest</directory>` to become `<directory>./AlbumTest/Controller/AlbumController.php</directory>` the test fails as desired.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Without seeing that file, I guess nobody will have a chance to see what is going on.

Comment: All the files come from the tutorial, with the exception of adding $this->assertTrue(false); as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not particularly keen on chasing a tutorial over the 'net... besides, in a few months it might be gone (or be edited out of recognition), and your question becomes just another complete mistery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPUnit looks for files that end with `Test.php`. Since your file is named `AlbumController.php`, it's being ignored. When you give PHPUnit the full path to the file, then it's reading it. So renaming the file to `AlbumControllerTest.php` should fix your problem.

Comment: Excellent, that solved my issue. Thank you so much for your help Tim. I wouldn't have known that before :P